# How in chrome/firefox devtool see big style content

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I am working on a website that a script is loading a big chunk of style in the HTML. my problem is the chrome dev tools don't let me view the full script. it's also not available in the resource tab and all chrome is doing is putting three dots while trimming the content. is there any way to view it in the dev tool? even if I copy the style content, it's trimmed version.

[image]

the same content in the firefox doesn't even load as something readable.

[image]

and I have to copy the content and reformat to see the result. wonder if there is any better way to do this?

Comment: Don't expand the element, just click it to select, then run `copy($0.textContent)` in the console. Then paste it in any editor.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox use [Style Editor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Style_Editor) tab in dev tools. from the official documentation:

> The Style Editor enables you to:
>
> - View and edit all the stylesheets associated with a page.
> - Create new stylesheets from scratch and apply them to the page.
> - Import existing stylesheets and apply them to the page.

You have (at least) 2 options to see this tab:

1. Hit `F12`, it will open up the Dev tools for you, then click on `Style Editor` tab.
2. Hit `Shift + F7`, it will open up the Dev tools and active `Style Editor` tab for you.

After opening the tab, you should be able to see all the stylesheets associated with a page in left pane (The style sheet pane), the name of inline stylesheets normally is something like `<inline style sheet #1>`, click on it, the content/css will show up in right pane (The editor pane).

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work for my case, if your style is coming from scss then you will see the scss and not the actual generated code. I think @wOxxOm answer is the best so far

Comment: What do you mean coming from scss? would you explain

Comment: if you create an angular project, in the style editor you will see a scss generated items. in the header you will see the actual one that is applied to the header. that's why I need to see the header content and not style editor items